# ASP.NET MVC - Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am making a project about movies. I want the movietitles to be displayed in a list on the startpage, when you click on one of the listitems it should redirect to a subpage (Movie.cshtml) with the movietitle in the url. The information on that page should be title, genre, year and country for that specific movie.

My StartController.cs:

```
using IMDB.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IMDB.Controllers
{
    public class StartController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Start
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var movieList = new List<Movies>();
            movieList.Add(new Movies() { Title = "Terminator", Genre = "Action", Year = 1984, Country = "America" });
            movieList.Add(new Movies() { Title = "Terminator II", Genre = "Action", Year = 1984, Country = "America" });

            return View(movieList);
        }

        public ActionResult Movie(string title)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I have already configured RouteConfig.cs to include Title in the url:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{title}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Start", action = "Index", title = "Title"
});
```

And the list of movies in my Index.cshtml:

```
@model List<IMDB.Models.Movies>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Start";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Welcome to My Movie Database</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var movie in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(movie.Title, "Movie", new { title = movie.Title})
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And this is my Movie.cshtml page:

```
@model IMDB.Models.Movies

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Movie";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div>
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</h2>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Year)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

So my question is, how do I get that unique information from my list?

Comment: are you getting from database or you are using in memory data structure as you have shown in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ***Class*** name should be always ***Singular*** - ***Movie***.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Second, you want to use Identifier when passing value in query string.

Title can be contain special character such as : &. If so, it won't be valid URL, and you won't be able to retrieve movie from title.

```
public class StartController : Controller
{
    // This could later comes from Database. 
    public IList<Movie> Movies
    {
        get
        {
            var movies = new List<Movie>
            {
                new Movie {Id = 1, Title = "Terminator", Genre = "Action", Year = 1984, Country = "America"},
                new Movie {Id = 2, Title = "Terminator II", Genre = "Action", Year = 1984, Country = "America"}
            };
            return movies;
        }
    }

    // GET: Start
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Movies);
    }

    public ActionResult Movie(int id)
    {
        var movie = Movies.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        return View(movie);
    }
}
```

### View

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var movie in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(movie.Title, "Movie", new { id = movie.Id})
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of the singular thing, but yeah sure!
I took your advice with using Identifier instead

Comment: Does it solve the problem or do you still have an issue related to original question?

Comment: Solves most of it

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, that the list you created in `Index` method will cease to exist after the page will be rendered. Client-side page have no connection to your code that is run on the server.

You will need to retrieve `Movie` data using only its name in your `Movie` method. E.g., if you're using a stub list instead of DB query, you will need to make it visible inside that method too:

```
public class StartController : Controller
{
    List<Movie> movieList = new List<Movies>()
    {
        new Movies() { Title = "Terminator", Genre = "Action", Year = 1984, Country = "America" },
        new Movies() { Title = "Terminator II", Genre = "Action", Year = 1984, Country = "America" }
    };

    // GET: Start
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(movieList);
    }

    public ActionResult Movie(string title)
    {
        var movie = movieList.Where(x => x.Title == title).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(movie);
    }
}
```

In this scenario you can, of course, just use list of titles in `Index` method instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another method in the controller with the modified route and parameters.

You should probably also store the movies somewhere, a repository perhaps?, instead of a list in another scope.

```
[HttpGet("movies/{title}")]
public ActionResult Movie(string title)
{
    // Recreate list here... or store it somewhere and query against it in the below line
    Movie movie = movieList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == title);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

Comment: ***Single*** will throw an exception, if Title is not found; it won't even reach to `if (movie == null)`

Comment: Thanks, I will amend

Comment: I have now made a repository instead, much better. Thanks